# Repeated linear programming with similar (not identical) problems

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have multiple linear programming problems of the form:

$$
\min\{c^{T}\cdot x\}\quad s.t. \quad Ax=b, x\ge 0
$$

Where $$ and $$ are fixed for all the problems. Is there any way to utilize that for a more efficient solution than solving each problem from scratch?

Currently I'm using [scipy's linprog](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html) but the performance is too slow given the amount of problems (thousands). I was wondering if there's a way to make this feasible with some smart preprocessing.
I've tried searching using terms such as "repeated linear programming", "repeated simplex" etc., but to no avail.

I also posted this question on [Computer Science stack exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/129339/repeated-linear-programming-with-similar-not-identical-problems).

Comment: Solve LP solvers allow you to *warm start* from a previous basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word you are looking for is "warm-start". That means the ability to start the simplex algorithm on the modified problem from the basis of the previous problem, rather than from scratch. Most of the serious LP solvers provide that.

You probably want to use the dual simplex algorithm since you are only changing $b$. A dual feasible point of one problem remains dual feasible after changing $b$ so you have more chances that the update required will be fast. Again, most solvers will provide that.

Comment: Thank you! That does seem to be what I'm looking for, I'll look into it.